# MongoDB - Get rank of the document based on frequency

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
[
    {_id: 1, query: 'A', createdAt: 1660610671 },
    {_id: 2, query: 'A', createdAt: 1660610672 },
    {_id: 3, query: 'A', createdAt: 1660610673 },
    {_id: 4, query: 'A', createdAt: 1660610674 },
    {_id: 5, query: 'B', createdAt: 1660610675 },
    {_id: 6, query: 'C', createdAt: 1660610676 },
    {_id: 7, query: 'C', createdAt: 1660610677 },
    {_id: 8, query: 'C', createdAt: 1660610678 },
    {_id: 9, query: 'D', createdAt: 1660610680 },
    {_id: 10, query: 'D', createdAt: 1660610681 },
]
```

I have the above database structure. I want to get rank from the frequency of the `query` value in a specific period.

Maybe it would be something like this.

```js
Queries.getRank({ key: 'query', createdAt: {$gte: startUnix, $lt: endUnix } })
```

I expect the result as below.

Rank

```
[
    {rank: 1, query: 'A', frequency: 4},
    {rank: 2, query: 'C', frequency: 3},
    {rank: 3, query: 'D', frequency: 2},
    {rank: 4, query: 'B', frequency: 1}
]
```

Is there a way to achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `$match` - Filter document within the range for `createdAt` field (if needed).
2. `$group` - Group by `query` and perform `$count` as `frequency`.
3. `$project` - Decorate the output document(s).
4. `$setWindowFields` - With [`$rank`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/rank/) to perform ranking by sorting `frequency` descending. May consider [`$denseRank`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/denseRank/) for the document with the same rank.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  // $match stage
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$query",
      frequency: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      query: "$_id",
      frequency: "$frequency"
    }
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: null,
      sortBy: {
        frequency: -1
      },
      output: {
        rank: {
          $rank: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kFQBPUx7iBj)

Comment: Do you know how do I `limit` the result length? If I want to get only Top 2

Comment: Aha- I done it. I added `$limit: 2` To last object of the array.

Comment: Either you can achieve by adding stage `{ $limit: 2 }` or `{ $match: { rank: { $lte: 2 } } }` as the last stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$query",
      "frequency": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "query": "$_id",
      "frequency": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      frequency: -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "array": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$array",
      "includeArrayIndex": "rank"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      rank: {
        "$add": [
          "$rank",
          1
        ]
      },
      frequency: "$array.frequency",
      query: "$array.query"
    }
  }
]);
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_IKppXHn9FQ)

In this, we first calculate the frequency for each query, then we sort it by the frequency, and finally, we push all documents in an array and calculate the rank, using array index.